# Jenkins not able to click button for python selenium script

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, jenkins

I am not able to click button for a `python` `selenium` script when I am running that script from `Jenkins`.

*Note* : The script works fine if I run that through command prompt in same server.

Below is the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type="submit"][@id="btnSubmitExport"][@class="Button"]"}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seem to be a timing issue. You should try to add few seconds of [ExplicitWait](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) till element appears in `DOM`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@type="submit"][@id="btnSubmitExport"][@class="Button"]'))).click()
```

Comment: Appreciated your answer but time is not a constraint here. I am already using time wait, though script is working fine through command prompt, only it is failing in Jenkins.

Comment: Share more details: your `Python` code you use to handle button, which browser you use, what exactly you want your script to perform

Comment: Script  clicks submit button on internal URL,   
Browser = Chrome,   

Piece of Code :
element_var = '//input[@type="submit"][@id="btnSubmitExport"][@class="Button"]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(element_var).click()

Comment: `Chrome` versions are the same on your local computer and on remote server where `Jenkins` located?

Comment: yes chrome version is same. Jenkins and the command prompt which I am using is in same server

Comment: Do you actually see this button when `Chrome` window is opened? Can you scrape `HTML` source code with `driver.page_source` to check whether there is an element with mentioned attributes?

Comment: Chrome window doesn't open while running through Jenkins. 
In my local system for few Jobs Jenkins doesn't opens Chrome window and jobs get successful.

Comment: Ok. So you can check `driver.page_source` or take page screenshot with `driver.get_screenshot_as_file('/path/to/file.png')` to check whether button really present on page

Comment: Thank You , After getting image got the real issue,
Actually the URL which I am providing to the script is a full path but it is  reflecting only home page address. So any clue now how to reflect full path.

Comment: Could you be more clear: what do you mean `URL which I am providing to the script`?

Comment: After lot of investigation found that the Jenkins open a browser in default resolution and do not maximize it, hence it is not able to find the element. while through command propmt without scrolling the page, it finds the element.

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved by myself...
Actually the problem is command prompt is running from windows user and the Jenkins slave machine is running from different User which does not have same access as Windows user.
To check user I used **whoami** command in command prompt as well as command prompt of Jenkins. This will give you the username.